# PROBLEM Getting a single field in a document in Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do a Cloud Function in Firebase. Initially, I read my document. Then I would take two fields "a" and "b", from this document. Then I want to set another field of my doc ('rank') as the sum of 'a' and 'b'. I can't find a solution!
I want to take only the fields "a" and "b" from my document. Save them in variables. And use those variables to do the sum, and set the result in "rank" field.

I tried:

```
var data = doc.data()
a = data.a
b = data.b
```

but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
export const daicazzo = functions.https.onRequest((request,response)=>{

  const store = admin.firestore();

  //var b;
  store.collection('questions').doc('LD92BBDOihAC3fHDyoV').get().then(doc =>{
    if(doc.exists){
      response.send(doc.data())
    }
    else{
      response.send("Nothing")
    }
  }).catch(reason => {
    console.log(reason)
    response.send(reason)
  })

  store.collection('questions').doc('LD92BBDOihAC3fHDyoV').set({
    rank: //a+b
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("done");
})
.catch(function(error){
  console.log("Error:",error);
});
});
```

Comment: You have to write the new value back to the document.  It won't write itself.

Comment: Pase the code from the image to the question so that someone can check the issue .

Comment: @Fire-In-D-Hole Or "paste" it.

Comment: @DougStevenson Apologies for the typo pasted the Code.

Answer (score 0):

Should do the work (might be some better solutions)

```
const store = admin.firestore();

export const daicazzo = functions.https.onRequest(async (request,response)=>{
   const questionRef = store.doc(`questions/${LD92BBDOihAC3fHDyoV}`)
   const doc = await questionRef.get()
   const foundDoc = doc.exists

   if (foundDoc) {
     // getting both key/value pairs from doc object
     const {a, b} = doc.data()

     const rank = a + b // whatever is your logic...

     // saving the rank in the same document
     await questionRef.update({rank}) // or questionRef.set({rank}, {merge: true})

     if you want to send back the doc with the updated rank without making another read, assuming you handle errors:
     const { id } = doc
     const updatedDoc = { ...doc.data(), id, rank }
     return response.send(updatedDoc)
   } else {
     return response.send("Nothing")
   }
});
```